# How to place Angular components side by side in web app

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to create a Web-app using Angular where a user can play a card game. A list of possible players should be depicted on the left, and the playing table should be to the right of the players list.

[Example of desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWz00.png)

However, since I'm using Angular and the players list and the playing table are different components, first the players list is shown and below that the playing table is located. [What it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLpl6.jpg)

My app.components.html looks like this:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<app-pippelaars></app-pippelaars> <!--component displaying available players-->
<app-playing-table></app-playing-table> <!--component displaying playing table-->
```

How do I get these components to be next to each other in the web app instead of one above the other?

Answer (score 0):

Since 2017 all major browsers support **CSS Grid layout**, you can use that to position your components correctly. To change the size of the colums you can use the '**grid-template-columns**' property and pass a fixed px value or use **fractional units** for a **responsive layout**.

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <app-pippelaars></app-pippelaars>
  <app-playing-table></app-playing-table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.grid-container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-areas: "players-list  playing-table";
   grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
}

 app-pippelaars { grid-area: players-list}
 app-playing-table { grid-area: playing-table}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try with flex layout, something like that:

in your scss file:

```
:host {
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 
 app-pippelaars {
  width: 300px
 } 

 app-playing-table {
  flex: 1;
 }
}
```

more information and example of flex layout can you read [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)